# Did Churchill urge the US to ‘wipe out’ Moscow with an A-bomb

Tags: history, politics, war, winston-churchill

I read the following article:

https://www.icij.org/blog/2014/10/churchill-urged-us-wipe-out-moscow-bomb/

from a seemingly reputable source (although it is a blog post).

The key claim:

> Privately, Churchill suggested that America strike first, before it was too late. According to FBI records, he urged Sen. Styles Bridges, a conservative Republican from New Hampshire active in foreign affairs, to back a preemptory and devastating attack on Moscow. “He [Churchill] pointed out that if an atomic bomb could be dropped on the Kremlin wiping it out, it would be a very easy problem to handle the balance of Russia, which would be without direction,” Bridges told the FBI.

The provided source is the following document:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-s3-1.icij.org/uploads/2017/10/00churchillfbi.png

How reliable are those claims?

Comment: There's some discussion at https://winstonchurchill.hillsdale.edu/did-churchill-bid-to-nuke-russia-2/.  They don't directly address whether the claimed conversation took place as described, but they cite other instances where he voiced similar opinions.  There may be some question as to how seriously he intended them to be taken.

Comment: @NateEldredge it is an interesting link but they try too hard to convince that he didn't *really* mean it.